# Branching process Durrett

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I don't understand the last "then" in that proof from Durrett.

It would be a relief if you can help me !

Thank you :).

[image: Durrett]

Comment: It would help if you defined the objects involved. What are $\mu, \xi_i^m$ and $Z_n$? I can make some guess from context but it would be helpful if I didn't have to guess what you mean (and possibly guess wrong)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can cut all the variables into groups of independant variables and get something that decrease to 0.